# Как вернуть тип boolean в функции?

Tags: golang, функции

Доброго времени суток.

Подскажите, как вернуть 2 значения из функции, одно из которых int, второе типа boolean.

```
func (number int) (int, bool?) {

return number, ?
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
func (number int) (int, bool) {
    return number, true
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, странно, не запустилось, когда так делал. Невнимательность. (